# Printing function name (to retrieve namespace) from compiler output

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces, clang, pragma

I am seeing some really weird errors in a complex file, and I suspect I have some include with namespaces left open, or something similar.
I cannot compile some file to an executable state.

To figure out what is the problem, I wanted to print the current namespace. I thought I would be fine using something like `__func__` (available since C++11) or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, but I cannot get to print it.

I cannot include it directly in a `#pragma message(__func__)` ("warning: expected a string after #pragma message"), and stringifying doesn't help, so namely, if I use this code:

```
#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_(x)

void fooMessage() {
#pragma message(STR(__func__))
}
```

I cannot get to print anything but the string `"__func__"`. It seems to work for `__LINE__`, but it's not useful for what I want to do...

Is there a way to have a pragma message to print the complete function name (or to know the current namespace) from clang and/or gcc compiler?

Some things I have tried are available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/534d5b5e21c73cb4)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but symbols with a leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter (like `_STR`) [are reserved in all scopes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: A problem with `__func__` is that e.g. `__LINE__` is handled like a preprocessor macro that expands to the current line, and `__func__` is a *variable* that is handled after after the preprocessor is finished.

Comment: Is #error handled any different than #pragma message as far as this expansion is concerned?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir `#error` looks even worse http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81bfd16e9534b63a (cannot convert even `__LINE__`)